# How to get aws account id from local configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm well aware of the `aws sts ...` method but that requires a remote call. Is there a way to get my account id/number from local configuration?

Comment: How would that even be possible? I work with multiple AWS accounts. Could you clarify a bit more what you mean by "local"?

Comment: When you use aws cli and type `aws s3 cp ...` for example, aws knows who you are based on your configured credentials (I assume). What I want to get is the account number associated with the configured profile without making that sts call. "How would that even be possible" is exactly what I'm asking in my question...